# Break XML File into multiple XML Files

Tags: perl, wsman

I want to break XML output given by WSMAN into multiple XML files so that I can parse the output.

WSMAN gives me output as below which basically has two distinct XML files with each having its own root node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Body>
    <wsen:PullResponse>
      <wsen:Items>
        <n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
          <n1:ComponentType>BIOS</n1:ComponentType>
          <n1:InstanceID>DCIM:CURRENT#741__BIOS.Setup.1-1</n1:InstanceID>
          <n1:VersionString>1.3.6</n1:VersionString>
        </n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
      </wsen:Items>
    </wsen:PullResponse>
  </s:Body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Body>
    <wsen:PullResponse>
      <wsen:Items>
        <n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
          <n1:ComponentType>BIOS</n1:ComponentType>
          <n1:InstanceID>DCIM:INSTALLED#741__BIOS.Setup.1-1</n1:InstanceID>
          <n1:VersionString>1.3.6</n1:VersionString>
        </n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
      </wsen:Items>
    </wsen:PullResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

I cannot parse above output with `XML::Simple` as above output contains 2 root elements which is "junk" in terms of [XML](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/#multiple_roots)

**Question/Statement:**

I want to break above output into two distinct XML files with each containing its own root element as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Body>
    <wsen:PullResponse>
      <wsen:Items>
        <n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
          <n1:ComponentType>BIOS</n1:ComponentType>
          <n1:InstanceID>DCIM:CURRENT#741__BIOS.Setup.1-1</n1:InstanceID>
          <n1:VersionString>1.3.6</n1:VersionString>
        </n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
      </wsen:Items>
    </wsen:PullResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Body>
    <wsen:PullResponse>
      <wsen:Items>
        <n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
          <n1:ComponentType>BIOS</n1:ComponentType>
          <n1:InstanceID>DCIM:INSTALLED#741__BIOS.Setup.1-1</n1:InstanceID>
          <n1:VersionString>1.3.6</n1:VersionString>
        </n1:DCIM_SoftwareIdentity>
      </wsen:Items>
    </wsen:PullResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

**My logic:**

1) Parse the output line by line

2) if you encounter `?xml version` pattern, then create a new XML file and write `?xml version` line and further lines to this new file until again you encounter `?xml version` pattern.

3) follow Step 2 every time you encounter `?xml version` pattern

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $counter = 0;
my $fileName;

while (my $line = <DATA>)
{
    if ( $line =~ /\?xml version/ )
    {   
        $counter++;
        print "Creating the BIOS file \n";
        $fileName = "BIOS"."_".$counter;
    }   
    open (my $sub_xml_file, ">" , $fileName) or die "Canot create $fileName: $!\n";
    print $sub_xml_file $line;
}

__DATA__
## omitting this part as this contains the XML info listed above.
```

Now, my script does create the files `BIOS_1` and `BIOS_2` but it writes only the last line of above XML output to it:

```
# cat BIOS_1
  </s:Body>
# cat BIOS_2
  </s:Body>
```

Can you help me fixing my script in order to create two distinct XML files...

Comment: You are opening (and truncating) the output file on every line of input. Declare 'my $sub_xml_file;' outside the while loop, and open($sub_xml_file,...) within the if block.

Comment: +1,@runrig, Your explanation is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never preserve `$line` for future loop passes.

Load everything in memory approach:

```
my $count;
my $file; { local $/; $file = <>; }
for my $xml (split /^(?=<\?xml)/m, $file) {
   my $fn = sprintf("BIOS_%d.xml", ++$count);
   open(my $fh, '>', $fn) or die $!;
   print $fh $xml;
}
```

Line at a time approach:

```
my $fh;
my $count;
while (<>) {
   if (/^<\?xml/) {
      my $fn = sprintf("BIOS_%d.xml", ++$count);
      open($fh, '>', $fn) or die $!;
   }

   print $fh $_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am working with the "line at a time" approach and it is working. could you please help me fix my code. I did not understand what you mean by "you never preserve $line"

Comment: The lines you read, you don't save them. So they're not available to you when you come to print.